# Mock of Rebus message context needs transaction

Tags: autofac, rebus

I have this code to mock a [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus) MessageContext

```
    IBus fakeBus;
    IMessageContext messageContext;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        fakeBus = new FakeBus();
        var mock = new Mock<IMessageContext>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.ReturnAddress).Returns("queuename");
        mock.Setup(h => h.Headers).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object>());
        mock.Setup(m => m.Items).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object>());
        mock.Setup(m => m.RebusTransportMessageId).Returns(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        messageContext = mock.Object;

        var fakeContext = FakeMessageContext.Establish(messageContext); // error here
   }
```

But the last line return the stack trace below.  What am I missing here?

Sidenote: I am still on Rebus 0.84.

Result StackTrace:

```
   at Rebus.MessageContext.Establish(IMessageContext messageContext, Boolean overwrite)
   at Rebus.Testing.FakeMessageContext.Establish(IMessageContext messageContext)
   at MyApp.Messaging.Tests.Handlers.RegisterPaymentCallbackTests.TestInitialize() in C:\CUT.Tests\Handlers\RegisterPaymentCallbackTests.cs:line 57
Result Message: Initialization method MyApp.Tests.Handlers.RegisterPaymentCallbackTests.TestInitialize threw exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a transaction context. There should always be a transaction context - though it might be a NoTransaction transaction context..
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really used the fake message context myself, as I've usually found it easier to either use `SagaFixture` or do my unit testing of slightly larger units.

When I look at the old Rebus code I can see that all the tests that exercise `FakeMessageContext` establish a transaction context first, like so:

`using (TransactionContext.None())
using (FakeMessageContext.Establish(fakeContext))
{
    // do stuff
}`

so that must be the way to do it :)

Comment: There is no ".None()" method.  But I guess that will do the same as Rebus.Bus.TransactionContext.Set(new Rebus.Bus.NoTransaction());

Comment: @dampee did you get this to work?  I'm using 0.84 as well but .None() is internal so I can't use.  Curious as to your solution